# Option Strict On prohibits operands of type Object for operator '&' in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, operators, operator-keyword

I have an error in the code below if I make the strict option to ON but if I make it OFF then the error does not appear. How can I use without error with the strict option being on?

Thanks

```
  Dim Invno As String = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value & String.Empty
```

Comment: Dim Invno As String = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.tostring & String.Empty

Comment: @ShahramAlemzadeh , can you answer as answer so I can mark your answer

Comment: Note that using `ToString` may throw an exception if it's possible for `Value` to be null.  If you know it can't be null then it's safe, otherwise I think you might need to use `CStr` instead.

Comment: @Craig , thanks for your reply you mean like this `Dim Invno As String = CStr(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value & String.Empty)` if this means it is safe for Value to be null and value not to be null

Comment: That code is ridiculous to begin with. What possible use could concatenating an empty string be? Please explain what you're actually trying to achieve and we'll explain the actual way to achieve it. There's no problem for which concatenating an empty string is the solution. If all you're trying to do is get a `String` from a cell then do that. There's no concatenation to be done in that case.

Comment: You should not be using `ToString` here unless the cell value is not a `String` to begin with but you want to convert it to one. If the cell value is a `String` already then, as is always the case, the solution is to cast: `Dim Invno = CStr(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value)`.

Comment: If you need the Invoice Number then that field should be part of the row's data keys. In general, you should never parse cell text (which is usually formatted for user readability) to get raw data.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , `You should not be using ToString here unless the cell value is not a String to begin with but you want to convert it to one. If the cell value is a String already then, as is always the case, the solution is to cast: Dim Invno = CStr(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value).` sorry i responded to you too late, thank you for your answer and suggestion, could you please answer as an answer so i can mark the answer

Comment: @fnostro , Thank you for your suggestion but the invoice number is indeed a data type string

Comment: Feel free to add your own answer.

Comment: @pret: That's fine, regardless of the data type it is bad practice to "scrape" table cells for data.  It's all "magic numbers", specifically cell index 0, which may change leaving you with bad data at best or a runtime exception at worst.  IMO, break that habit.

Comment: @fnostro , thanks for your suggestion, you mean I'd better use `SelectedRows(0). DataBoundItem`

Comment: @pret: Both really, hard coded indexes are, generally speaking, bad programing style. When searching for a value in some form of grid we typically iterate through ALL rows whether it's a *For* loop or *For Each*. But data columns may change position, so expecting data at a specific index may bite us sometime in the future if someone alters the data source or takes over your code and doesn't have your familiarity.

Answer (score 0):

Solution This perfect answer comes from @jmcilhinney

```
Dim Invno = CStr(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value)
```